# "_PropertyDeferred' error when accesing a List of Lists

Tags: python, scripting, error

I have a list of lists declared like this:

```
class SuperFaceID(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    m_face_index = bpy.props.IntProperty()
bpy.utils.register_class(SuperFaceID)    

class SuperFaceParentGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    m_faces_group = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SuperFaceID)
bpy.utils.register_class(SuperFaceParentGroup)    

bpy.types.Scene.PolyList = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SuperFaceParentGroup)
```

But when I try to check what is inside in a loop:

```
for l_face_group_save in bpy.types.Scene.PolyList.m_faces_group:
```

Or when I try to add something:

```
l_face_group = []
for p in l_mesh.polygons:
    if p.select:
        l_face_group.append(p.index)

bpy.types.Scene.PolyList.append(l_face_group)
```

In both cases I get an error, this one for the loop:

> AttributeError: '_PropertyDeferred' object has no attribute
> 'm_faces_group'

And this one when I try to append:

> AttributeError: '_PropertyDeferred' object has no attribute 'append'

How should I access this list of list and add items to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `bpy.types.Scene.PolyList = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SuperFaceParentGroup)`, you are instantiating a `CollectionProperty` that can hold items of type `SuperFaceParentGroup` so you can't access `m_faces_group` on `bpy.types.Scene.PolyList` because `PolyList` is of type `CollectionProperty` but `m_faces_group` is part of `SuperFaceParentGroup`, which is the type defined for the items that your `CollectionProperty` can hold. So instead, you have to add an item to the `CollectionProperty` via `add()`:

```
bpy.types.Scene.PolyList = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SuperFaceParentGroup)
super_face_parent_group = bpy.context.scene.PolyList.add()
m_faces_group = super_face_parent_group.m_faces_group
```

Then you can add items to the `m_faces_group` and iterate over them. Here's a working example:

```
import bpy

class SuperFaceID(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    m_face_index: bpy.props.IntProperty()

class SuperFaceParentGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    m_faces_group: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SuperFaceID)

bpy.utils.register_class(SuperFaceID)
bpy.utils.register_class(SuperFaceParentGroup)

# instantiate a CollectionProperty that can hold items of type SuperFaceParentGroup
bpy.types.Scene.PolyList = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SuperFaceParentGroup)

# add an instance of type SuperFaceParentGroup and store in super_face_parent_group
super_face_parent_group = bpy.context.scene.PolyList.add()

m_faces_group = super_face_parent_group.m_faces_group

# add 2 items to the m_faces_group
SuperFaceID_item_1 = m_faces_group.add()
SuperFaceID_item_1.m_face_index = 13
SuperFaceID_item_2 = m_faces_group.add()
SuperFaceID_item_2.m_face_index = 47

# iterate over the 2 items:
for SuperFaceID_item in m_faces_group:
    print(SuperFaceID_item.m_face_index)
```

Comment: You are a hero! Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry to bring another question here, would you know how to iterate through bpy.context.scene.PolyList? if I use it like so, it says is not iteratable, and also methods like ""values()" are not present either

Comment: you can just use a the same `for` loop `for super_face_parent_group in bpy.context.scene.PolyList:`